# 306_expandable_grid - cannot read the property of 'data' undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

i am working on ui-grid and 306_expandable_grid , i have used the exact code as in the doc but i am facing a problem with an error .

app.js

```
$http.get('resources/data/title2.json')
    .success(function(data){

        console.log(data);
        console.log(data[0].Data);
        console.log(data.length);
        for(i = 0; i < data[i].length; i++){
           data[i].subGridOptions = {
                  columnDefs: [ 
                    {name:"Title" },
                    {name:"Jan-10" },
                    {name:"Feb-10"},
                    {name:"Mar-10" },
                    {name:"Apr-10" },
                    {name:"May-10" },
                    {name:"Jun-10" },
                    {name:"Jul-10" },
                    {name:"Aug-10" },
                    {name:"Sep-10" },
                    {name:"Oct-10" },
                    {name:"Nov-10" },
                    {name:"Dec-10" }
                ],
              data: data[i].Data
          }
      }
        // $scope.subGridOptions.data = data;
        $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
        // $scope.title = data[0].Title;
    });
```

externalHtmlFile.html

```
<div ui-grid="row.entity.subGridOptions" style="height:150px;"></div>
```

this is the error that i am stuck with

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost/ng-Grid/resources/scripts/ui-grid-unstable.js:2883:41)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://localhost/ng-Grid/resources/scripts/angular.min.js:36:456)
    at E.instance (http://localhost/ng-Grid/resources/scripts/angular.min.js:75:118)
    at http://localhost/ng-Grid/resources/scripts/angular.min.js:58:276
    at r (http://localhost/ng-Grid/resources/scripts/angular.min.js:7:408)
    at M (http://localhost/ng-Grid/resources/scripts/angular.min.js:58:260)
    at http://localhost/ng-Grid/resources/scripts/angular.min.js:65:412
    at http://localhost/ng-Grid/resources/scripts/angular.min.js:109:276
    at h.$eval (http://localhost/ng-Grid/resources/scripts/angular.min.js:123:139)
    at h.$digest (http://localhost/ng-Grid/resources/scripts/angular.min.js:120:220)
```

when i click on the plus icon , the error occurs ... i could not find out a solution that i can understand . please help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, make sure that you initialize `$scope.gridOptions` outside of `$http.get` `success` callback. Only add the `$scope.gridOptions.data[i].subGridOptions` to `$scope.gridOptions` inside the `success` callback. [Reference](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/60):

> You can't define the grid options in the success call. You need to define them on the scope in your controller and then set the data or column definitions, etc... from the success call.

Second, make sure that the controller of the grid/page doesn't have any kind of initialization parameter-dependent redirects.  I faced the same error message generated because of the following piece of code I had on the page:

```
if (typeof clientcode === 'string' && clientcode !== '') {

    var payload = {
        clientcode : storedClientcode
    }

} else {

    $location.path('/');

}
```

The idea here was to check if the `storedClientcode` was provided by the calling page (via a shared app root service), and if not, redirect to the application home. But **the ui-grid apparently makes separate sub-calls to the page its on**, and those sub-calls of course do not provide the data I was looking for with my code, and so the redirect occurred behind the scenes for those calls.  No errors (other than what you also saw) were produced, and no data showed up in the grid. This took me some time to figure out (I'm fairly new with AngularJS, and this was the first application of ui-grid for me).. hopefully this will help someone, even if it doesn't resolve this question.

Comment: yes ,thanks for the explanation sir ... even i am new to angularJS . i figured out what was going wrong , i am writing it down . The `field` argument in `columnDefs : [{name:'title' , **field: 'title'**}, ...];` was giving me problem in my context , i had defined the scope of gridoptions like this 
`$scope.gridOptions = {
    expandableRowTemplate: 'externalhtmlfile.html',
    expandableRowHeight: 300,
    aggregationHideLabel: false
  }`. 
  it took some time for me to understand its `field` to which the data is being binded to.

Comment: Also note that `field` is an alias to `name` available for backward compatibility purposes. [API docs](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions) say: "field property can be used in place of name for backwards compatibility with 2.x". You can use `displayName` to change the way the column is titled on the grid, like so: `{ name: 'field1', displayName: 'pretty display name' }`.

Comment: I had the same issue. I gave the gridOptions before the http.get call and given the scope.gridOptions{data: GET RESPONSE DATA} inside the success section.